# I use $_POST and index is undefined?

Tags: php, search, indexing, undefined

I am using the code show below for a search and it is working. But when I try it to display another page with other results it says that “the index is undefined". I'm using  again in this file but it does not solve anything. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

The error is:

> Notice: Undefined index: pesquisa in J:\xampp\htdocs\pesquisa3.php on line 32

The code is:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
        header ("Location: login.php");
    }
?>  

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Registo</title>  
    </head>

    <body background="/images/farm.jpg">
        <center>
                <h1>Pesquisa em Mugidor</h1>
                <?php
                    $dbh = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","")
                        or die("Erro ao ligar-me a base de dados -> ".mysql_error());
                    $db = mysql_select_db("users", $dbh)
                        or die("Erro ao escolher a base de dados -> ".mysql_error());
                    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $dbh);

                    // verificação da existência de pesquisa
                    $pesquisa = $_POST['pesquisa'];
                    if(!empty($_POST['pesquisa']))
                    {
                        // tabela onde vai ocorrer a pesquisa
                        $table = "mugidos";
                        // páginas adjacentes na numero de paginas de resultados
                        $adjacents = 1;
                        // explode as palavras colocadas na pesquisa em arrays
                        $arraySearch = explode(" ", $pesquisa);
                        // campos a pesquisar na tabela
                        $arrayFields = array(0 => "hashtag");
                        $countSearch = count($arraySearch);
                        $a = 0;
                        $b = 0; 
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE (";
                        $countFields = count($arrayFields);
                        while ($a < $countFields)
                        {
                            while ($b < $countSearch)
                            {
                                $query = $query."$arrayFields[$a] LIKE '%$arraySearch[$b]%'";
                                $b++;
                                if ($b < $countSearch)
                                {
                                    $query = $query." AND ";
                                }
                            }
                            $b = 0;
                            $a++;
                            if ($a < $countFields)
                            {
                                $query = $query.") OR (";
                            }
                        }
                        $query = $query.")";
                        $query_result = mysql_query($query);
                        $numberrows = mysql_num_rows($query_result);
                        $pagenum= $numberrows / 4;
                        // resultados
                        echo '<h1>Resultados</h1>'."\n\n";
                        if($numberrows < 1)
                        {
                            echo '<p>Não foram encontrados resultados para "'.$pesquisa.'"</p>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 0; 
                            if($page) 
                            {
                            $inicio = ($page - 1) * 10;
                            $fim = ($page * 10);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            $inicio = 0;
                            $fim = 4;
                            }
                            $query = $query."LIMIT $inicio, $fim";
                            $query_result2 = mysql_query($query);
                            echo '<p>Resultados da pesquisa de "'.$pesquisa.'":</p>'."\n\n";
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result2))
                            {
                                $remugido = $row['mugido'] ;
                                $repostador = $row['postador'] ;
                                $rehashtag = $row['hashtag'] ;
                                $rerepostador = $row['repostador'];
                                // aqui aparece o output da pesquisa
                                if($rerepostador === NULL)
                                {
                                    echo "<table border='1' bordercolor='000000' style='background-color:FFFFFF' width='800' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='3'>";
                                    echo "<TR><TD width='70%'>","\n";
                                    echo "<strong>";
                                    echo $repostador;
                                    echo "</strong> ";
                                    echo $remugido;
                                    echo " <br><strong><font size='1'>";
                                    echo $row['timestamp'];
                                    echo "</strong></font>";
                                    echo "<form action='retweet.php' method='post'>";
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
                                    echo $remugido;
                                    echo "' name='remugido' style='height: 25px; width: 75px'><input type='submit' value='Re-Muuuu!' />";
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
                                    echo $repostador;
                                    echo "' name='repostador' />";
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
                                    echo $rehashtag;
                                    echo "' name='rehashtag' />";
                                    echo "</form>";
                                    echo "</TD>","\n";                  
                                    echo "</TR></table>" ,"\n";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "<table border='1' bordercolor='000000' style='background-color:FFFFFF' width='800' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='3'>";
                                    echo "<TR><TD width='70%'>","\n";
                                    echo "<strong>";
                                    echo $repostador;
                                    echo "</strong> ";
                                    echo " via ";
                                    echo "<strong>";
                                    echo $row['repostador'];
                                    echo "</strong> ";
                                    echo $remugido;
                                    echo " <br><strong><font size='1'>";
                                    echo $row['timestamp'];
                                    echo "</strong></font>";
                                    echo "<form action='retweet.php' method='post'>";
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
                                    echo $remugido;
                                    echo "' name='remugido' style='height: 25px; width: 75px'><input type='submit' value='Re-Muuuu!' />";
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
                                    echo $repostador;
                                    echo "' name='repostador' />";
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
                                    echo $rehashtag;
                                    echo "' name='rehashtag' />";
                                    echo "</form>";
                                    echo "</TD>","\n";                  
                                    echo "</TR></table>" ,"\n";                 
                                }
                            }
                            echo "<form method='post'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$pagenum'>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
                            echo $pesquisa;
                            echo "' name='pesquisa'><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Proxima pagina'></a></form>";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo ("Insira pelo menos um termo de pesquisa.<br />Redirecionando em 3 segundos.");
                        header ("Refresh: 3; url=page5.php");
                        die();
                    }
                ?>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post the specific error message in full? Otherwise we don't know which variable is actually undefined.

Comment: are you sure your $_POST['pesquisa'] is available to use, since it's in an `if` statement you could be hitting the else? Does the error give you a line number?

Comment: the $_POST is working when the search form is submited, but when you try to display more results (other page) it doesnt know what $_POST['pesquisa'] is anymore. the error is on the question

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$pesquisa = $_POST['pesquisa'];
```

to

```
$pesquisa = (isset($_POST['pesquisa'])) ? $_POST['pesquisa'] : '';
// or
$pesquisa = @$_POST['pesquisa']; // suppress warning if not set

// and then change 
if(!empty($_POST['pesquisa']))
// to
if(trim($pesquisa) != ''))
```

You are trying to assign `$_POST['pesquisa'];` but that value is only set if the search form was filled out.

Also change:

```
echo "<form method='post'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$pagenum'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
echo $pesquisa;
echo "' name='pesquisa'><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Proxima pagina'></a></form>";
```

to

```
echo "<form method='post' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$pagenum'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
echo htmlspecialchars($pesquisa);
echo "' name='pesquisa'><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Proxima pagina'></form>";
```

Comment: the search form is filled and it displays the first page of results, but when i try to display 4 more results (other page) it gives me the error

Comment: and btw i changed what you said and it gave me:
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in J:\xampp\htdocs\pesquisa3.php on line 32"

Comment: I see, it is because clicking the link is not submitting the form, it is linking to `page.php?pagenum=X` but not via POST.  If you want to use the link and not a regular submit button to send the form, you will need to use `onclick` to submit the form.

Comment: Sorry, should have been `$pesquisa = (isset($_POST['pesquisa'])) ? $_POST['pesquisa'] : '';` missed one extra `)`

Comment: and how do i set it to go to pagenum=X with onclick?

Comment: See updated answer.  I didn't use the onclick method since that requires javascript which some may have disabled.  If you want to use javascript, you can use `<a href='#' onclick="document.getElementById('search').submit(); return false">Search</a>` and add `<form id="search"...>`

Comment: that did the trick, i now get "pesquisa3.php?pagenum=2" in the link, but the search results don't change. pff :(

Comment: Echo your query prior to executing to make sure the limits and page numbers are being calculated and set properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

```
                echo "<form method='post'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$pagenum'>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
                echo $pesquisa;
                echo "' name='pesquisa'><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Proxima pagina'></a></form>";
```

You are putting an `input` element inside a `a` tag. That's just wrong, you need to add another hidden variable to your form with the page-number so that you can get it when the form is re-posted.

Something like:

```
echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='pagenum' value='" . (intval($_POST['pagenum']) + 1) . "' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
echo $pesquisa;
echo "' name='pesquisa'><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Proxima pagina'></form>";
```

After that obviously you have to get the value of `pagenum` and adjust the limit clause in your query to accommodate it.

**Edit:** I missed it the first time, you are using:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 0;
```

So you need to use the variable `$page` in the form at the bottom as well, instead of `$pagenum` (I use post, but it's the same for get):

```
$page = (isset($_POST['page'])) ? (int)$_POST['page'] : 0;
```

...

```
echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='page' value='" . (intval($_POST['page']) + 1) . "' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
echo $pesquisa;
echo "' name='pesquisa'><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Proxima pagina'></form>";
```

Comment: The thing is that i don't know how to get the value of pagenum

Comment: @MrM1k4d0 See my edit, there is a mixup between `$page` and `$pagenum`

Comment: im using that, but i got:

Notice: Undefined index: page in J:\xampp\htdocs\pesquisa3.php on line 166

Comment: @MrM1k4d0 I was mixing things up a bit as well, you have to use or `$_GET` or `$_POST`, I have changed the example above to all `$_POST`.

Comment: I still get an error "Notice: Undefined index: page in J:\xampp\htdocs\pesquisa3.php on line 166". But now when i click the button it gives me more results, in a random way tough