# Simple PHP button to send to next page

Tags: php, search, button, pagination

I have this:

```
echo "<form method='post' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$pagenum'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='";
echo htmlspecialchars($pesquisa);
echo "' name='pesquisa'><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Proxima pagina'></form>";
```

But I need only a button that when clicked for the first time, sends to page two. When it's clicked again on that page two, send do page three and so on. How do I do this in a simple way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already posted a possible solution to one of your previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705013/i-use-post-and-index-is-undefined

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705013/i-use-post-and-index-is-undefined as @jeroen already said.

Answer (score 2):

You should just use a link instead of a form. if it must look like a button, you can use an image.

```
echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$pagenum\"><img src=\"button.jpg\" /></a>";
```

Comment: Agreed, but use single quote instead double quote for PHP string may have speed increase like this: `echo '<a href="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?pagenum=', $pagenum, '"><img src="button.jpg"></a>';`

Comment: There's no reason to worry about such micro-optimisations. The performance difference is negligable.

Comment: In fact, I originally used single quote (they are faster!) but then I switched it back because the asker had used double quotes

Comment: As for making it look like a button, you can give the anchor a class, and in CSS make it display as a block, text indent -9999, and design as needed. double quotes and single quote micro-optimizations are almost silly.

Comment: I don't micro optimize, i just try to only use single :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $pagenum starts at 0.

```
if($_POST['pesquisa'])
{
    $pagenum++;
}
else
{
    $pagenum = 0;
}
```

That way your first page view you wont have a $_POST['pagenum'] so it sets to 0. After that you will have one as your passing it along and then you increment the value for the next button press.

Comment: ok i got that, but how do i define the variable $pagenum? if i dont, i will get an error when i run that script:

Notice: Undefined variable: pagenum in J:\xampp\htdocs\pesquisa3.php on line 35

Answer (score 0):

Here the button:

```
$pesquisa = 'label';
$pagenum = 100500;

echo "<input type='button' onclick='location.href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum={$pagenum}\"'";
echo " value='" . htmlspecialchars($pesquisa) . "'/>";
```

All logic to change current page to next one showed in previous answers.